# Invalid Index is Zero on Playing Song

Tags: android

I am creating a music player app. I have two classes named "Tab3Tracks" and "NowPlaying". In "Tab3Tacks" class, songs are loaded in ListView. So that when someone clicks on a song, it sends position of that song to other class so that other class will able to play that song. But i am getting error while clicking on song. I dont know where i am making mistake. In logcat, i received error "Invalid Index 0, size is 0" in NowPlaying class. I am posting LogCat error code. Check my code for any mistakes. Thanks in advance.

**Tab3Tracks Class**

```
public class Tab3Tracks extends ListFragment {


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

private ArrayList<String> trackslist = new ArrayList<>();


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3tracks, container, false);


    final String trackid = MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID;
    final String trackno = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TRACK;
    final String trackname = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE;
    final String path = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA;
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    ContentResolver cr = getContext().getContentResolver();
    final String[] projection = {trackid,trackno,trackname,path
    };
    final Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri,projection,null,null,null);
    if (cursor!=null){
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                int trackIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
                trackslist.add(cursor.getString(trackIndex));
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    } cursor.close();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity(),R.layout.playlist_item,R.id.songTitle,trackslist
    );
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    return v;
}


public ArrayList<String> getList(){
    return trackslist;
}



@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    int songIndex = position;

    // Starting new intent
    Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), NowPlaying.class);
    // Sending songIndex to PlayerActivity
    in.putExtra("songIndex", songIndex);
    startActivityForResult(in, 100);
    getActivity().finish();
}
}
```

**NowPlaying Class**

```
  public class NowPlaying extends AppCompatActivity {

  public ArrayList<String> songsList = new ArrayList<String>();
  public Tab3Tracks tab3tracks;


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.player);
    // Getting all songs list
    tab3tracks = new Tab3Tracks();
    songsList= tab3tracks.getList();


  // By default play first song
    playSong(0);

 }



 /**
 * Receiving song index from playlist view
 * and play the song
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
                                int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        currentSongIndex = data.getExtras().getInt("songIndex");
        // play selected song
        playSong(currentSongIndex);
    }

}

 /**
 * Function to play a song
 *
 * @param songIndex - index of song
 */
public void playSong(int songIndex) {
    // Play song
    try {
        mp.reset();
        mp.setDataSource(songsList.get(songIndex));
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
        // Displaying Song title
        String songTitle = songsList.get(songIndex);
        songTitleLabel.setText(songTitle);

        // Changing Button Image to pause image
        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);

        // set Progress bar values
        songProgressBar.setProgress(0);
        songProgressBar.setMax(100);

        // Updating progress bar
        updateProgressBar();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**LogCat Error**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity    ComponentInfo{com.digital.thefearstuff.tfsmusicplayer/com.digital.thefearstuff.tfsmusicplayer.NowPlaying}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2450)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
        at com.digital.thefearstuff.tfsmusicplayer.NowPlaying.playSong(NowPlaying.java:286)
        at com.digital.thefearstuff.tfsmusicplayer.NowPlaying.onCreate(NowPlaying.java:83)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, please avoid asking such questions as *Why is this code not working?* seeking debug help, since they tend to get a lot of downvotes and are usually quickly closed off. Always try to minimize and isolate your problem. **Debug by yourself** and see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for future posts.

Now to question, here in `playSong(0)` you try to access element at position `0` but the list is empty and there is no such position, therefore `IndexOutOfBounds`.

```
    at com.digital.thefearstuff.tfsmusicplayer.NowPlaying.playSong(NowPlaying.java:286)
    at com.digital.thefearstuff.tfsmusicplayer.NowPlaying.onCreate(NowPlaying.java:83)
```

Your `songsList` is as it turns out - empty. Which in turn means that `trackslist` is empty. Which for itself could lead to `cursor` being `null` and skipping the `add`-while-loop. But that you should debug by yourself since you only have the whole code.

To debug it: Add an `else` and `Log` with the `if (cursor != null){` such as

```
if (cursor!=null){
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            int trackIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            trackslist.add(cursor.getString(trackIndex));
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
} else {
    Log.d("cursor", "null");
}
cursor.close();
```

and look for it in the logcat.

Comment: I tried to check the size of array list in both classes ... In "Tab3tracks" class, it shows a positive value but in "NowPlaying" class, it shows the size zero.

Comment: Have you added the Fragment to your activity's layout then [Creating a Fragment](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html#AddInLayout) and *Adding a fragment to an activity* and *Managing fragments* of [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)?